# Generating unique ids shared between distributed databases from a Java application

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb

I'm working in a Java application that, among other functionalities, must persist information in a database (we are going to implement MySQL for one client, and MongoDB for another client). The operational behavior of this functionaliy is to communicate different users to exchange messages and information, and these users might share the same database (centralized) or have different databases (decentralized), and I must ensure that, when dealing with decentralized databases, I don't have duplicated IDs, or same IDs referring to different information.

To achieve this, I'm thinking about not giving to the databases the responsibility of auto generating the IDs (as in relational databases I might have the same ID but with different information in the row), and to create the ID from the application using the hashCode of the object I want to persist in the database, saving this element in my database, and sending it to another user. This other user will receive the message, and save it in its database with the same ID I have, so we can refer to the same message using the same ID in the future.

As the hashCodes might be repeated because of their 32-bit nature, and I will have in the database more records than the ones that can be generated with 32 bits, I'm thinking the following: to create an "idGenerator()" function that returns a value like: "object hashCode + datetime when the element was generated in the application (in miliseconds)". By this way, I'm trying to reduce the probability of having duplicated IDs in the database. I'm thinking about returning something like a double, which would give me 2^64 combinations instead of 2^32 if I return an integer.

Maybe this approach might difficult the way I can search for elements in the database later, but this is the first time I have to deal with different databases that must contain the same IDs for the elements they are exchanging.

Could you give me feedback about this approach? And also, if there is another way to deal with IDs in decentralized databases, could you give me references? I'm new in these kind of implementations so any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: I would not leave this task to the individual databases as there probably are inconsistencies how UUIDs / GUIDs are generated. As the answer to the duplicate question points it out, java has a GUID implementation, use that for generating unique ids across your app.